# Ajax chained completion event (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, ajax

Let's say I have a function as follows:

```
function load_form() {
    $( '.result' ).load( '/form.html', function() {
        console.log( 'form loaded.' );
    } );
}
```

This loads a form via ajax. (In reality it loads different forms depending on the radio that's selected and then sets up events on different elements once loaded)

So in another part of the code I write:

```
load_form();
```

No problem! Then somewhere else I write another `load_form()`...again no problem. (Basically when adding data via the form)

Further down, I need to load the form but do something different afterwards: (For example after I click to load form I then need to populate it with data)

```
load_form();
//afterwards I need it to run this function
populate_form();
```

I figured I would chain it as follows:

```
function load_form() {
    return $( '.result' ).load( '/form.html', function() {
        console.log( 'form loaded.' );
    } );
}

$promise = load_form();
$.when( $promise ).done( populate_form );
```

...but this doesn't work as I would have hoped. Instead of running the console.log and then the populate_form() it runs the populate_form() and then the console.log. (Which in this case isn't a problem, but in the real code the order is important)

I also tried:

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete( populate_form );
```

However, this didn't work as it ran every time and then when I tried to cancel it as follows:

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete( function() {
    populate_form();
    $(document).unbind( "ajaxComplete" );
});
```

So any ideas how to add a specific function to a completed ajax call on a per-request basis?

Thanks
Jim

Comment: The callback added directly in the `load_form` function will always be called before any other chained callbacks.

Comment: Was my answer helpful to you? Or is that not what you wanted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get `load_form` to take a callback and call it once the load is complete.

```
function load_form(callback) {
    $( '.result' ).load( '/form.html', function() {
        console.log( 'form loaded.' );
        if(callback)
            callback();
    } );
}

load_form(populate_form);
```

This also allows you to pass arguments to your callback like this:

```
user = {username : 'Jim Win'};
load_form(function() {
    populate_form(user);
});
```